# Redesign the PTN04050A

Tags: dc-dc-converter

for an old project I need to replace the Texas PTN04050A module (which is no longer available) with an equivalent module.
Since I don't want to change anything else, I would like to redesign an equivalent module, with the same dimensions and the same pinout.

The problem is that the characteristics of this module are quite particular, and searching on the internet I cannot find chips or modules that have the same characteristics. The module in question has:

Vin: from 2.9V to 7V
Vout: from -15V to -3.3V
Power: 6W

The output voltage must be configurable with a resistor:
[image]

Can you help me find a chip with which to make a module with those characteristics?

Comment: See this https://octopart.com/ptn04050aah-texas+instruments-580797?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIieP5uYbQgQMVvJ9oCR35rA8jEAAYASAAEgIbJfD_BwE

Comment: Search this https://www.tracopower.com/int/product-finder/dc-dc?power_min=0&power_max=400&input_voltage_min=0&input_voltage_max=400&input_voltage_selection=within_range&main_output_voltage_min=0&main_output_voltage_max=100&isolation=non_isolated

Comment: That voltage set resistor is weird. I don't think you're going to find anything else that has that same characteristic. What chip does the module use?

Comment: @Antonio51I have caught many scams on that site, it is a very old product, only replacing it is a safe way. Instead, those of tracopower are only with positive output.

Comment: @Hearth I don't know, it would be nice to find out.

Comment: @Antonio51 Octopart is useful, but you should never order from the hollow-star sites it lists--they almost never actually have the parts in stock that they claim, and will frequently send you counterfeits.

Comment: @Hearth ok. Thank you for the informations.